# How to set up these email headers with Mailgun API

Tags: php, api, email, curl, mailgun

I'm using curl with PHP to communicate with MailGun API. 
I have two emails which I need my recipients to receive the email with following headers.
Could you give me an example code snippet in curl (or curl library for PHP) for achieve these mail headers?

-- Email 1 --

```
From: "My Name"

Content-type: text/plain;charset="iso-8859-1"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

-- Email 2 --

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

From:my.domain.com <customerservice@mydomain.com>

Reply-To: my.domain.com <customerservice@mydomain.com>

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="=_730dc78ab764a3e997c2c451d9352d87"

Message-ID: <ndfmzn.jquf15@my.domain.com>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add as many headers as you want inside the array as long as they're prefixed with "h:" look at the line

```
'h:Message-Id'=>  'ndfmzn.jquf15@my.domain.com', //Your Message-ID
```

Below some larger explanation of how you can implement this:

```
<?php
$mg_api = 'key-XXX'; //YOUR API KEY
$mg_version = 'api.mailgun.net/v2/'; //ROOT URL FOR MAILGUN
$mg_domain = "samples.mailgun.org"; //YOUR DOMAIN AS SPECIFIED IN THE CONTROL PANEL
$mg_from_email = "info@samples.com"; // YOUR FROM EMAIL
$mg_reply_to_email = "info@samples.org"; // YOUR REPLY-TO EMAIL (USUALLY MATCHES FROM EMAIL)

$mg_message_url = "https://".$mg_version.$mg_domain."/messages";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $mg_api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mg_message_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,                
        array(  'from'      => 'you@domain.com',
                'to'        => 'receiver@receiver.com',
                'h:Reply-To'=>  ' <' . $mg_reply_to_email . '>',
                'h:Message-Id'=>  'ndfmzn.jquf15@my.domain.com', //Your Message-ID
                'subject'   => 'Hello',
                'html'      => 'Mailgun POW POW!'
            ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($result,TRUE);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it OK to pass the MIME-Version header to Mailgun?

Comment: I've never tried that specifically, I think it will be okay but it's worth just testing it :)

Comment: How to set headers within mailgun API?

Comment: I'm having an issue with Mailgun API sending my HTML part of my email as the following; which is causing issues with my "mobile" email responsive view:

Content-Type: text/html; charset="ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

So can I use the following with Mailgun API to set this to "utf-8"?

'h:charset' => 'utf-8',

Thank you!

Comment: @YesItsMe No, wasn't able to find a solution for this.