# How to set up headers "h:Reply-To" with Mailgun php API

Tags: php, api, laravel, mailgun

How to set up headers "Reply-to" in Mailgun php API?

I've using this code but can't imaging hot to set up headers

```
Mail::send('email.message', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['to_email'], $data['to_name'])
                ->subject($data['subject'])
                ->from($data['from_email'], $data['from_name']);
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361595/how-to-set-up-these-email-headers-with-mailgun-api

Comment: @SomeHelpingDude I know how to use search. I'm looking for decision within Mailgun php API not with CURL and raw php.

Comment: I already answered the similar question. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338842/how-to-add-headers-to-email-in-laravel-5-1/32341951#32341951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as adding a **replyTo** on your `$message` chain

```
Mail::send('email.message', $data, function($message) use($data)
{
    $message->to($data['to_email'], $data['to_name'])
        ->subject($data['subject'])
        ->from($data['from_email'], $data['from_name'])
        ->replyTo('REPLY.TO.THIS@email.com');
});
```

if you want to add a name to the reply to, just add another parameter with the name:

```
->replyTo('REPLY.TO.THIS@email.com', 'Arsen Ibragimov')
```

Comment: thanks for response. Is it possible to set up "name <email@email.com>" in headers?

Comment: yes you can just add another parameter like: `->replyTo('REPLY.TO.THIS@email.com', 'Arsen Ibragimov')`;

Comment: I had to use `->reply_to` instead.